# Can a clause be added to a terms of use that forbids use of the service if the terms of use would be illegal in the user's jurisdiction?

Tags: contract-law, gdpr

Can one add a clause stating

> Do not use this application if the terms demanded cannot be provided by law

For example, let's say one term of use states that information collected may be retained forever, which is not possible in countries subject to the GDPR.  In this case, users would be required not to use the application.

Comment: Are you selling your non-GDPR-compliant program with a price in Euros?

Comment: Am not selling anything already I just want to know the law.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can a clause be added to a terms of use that forbids use of the service if the terms of use would be illegal in the user's jurisdiction?

Yes, but that is redundant because contracts --or portions thereof-- which contravene the law are null and void.

> let's say one term of use states that information collected may be retained forever, which is not possible in countries subject to the GDPR

That premise is mistaken in contexts which involve a *necessity for the performance of a contract*. See recital 40 and article 6.1(b) of the [GDPR](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/eli/reg/2016/679/oj). That necessity needs to be true (see recital 43) and ongoing (*cf.* article 17.1(a)).

Likewise, data retention might be required for *compliance with a legal obligation to which the controller is subject*. See articles 6.1.(c) and 17.3(b)-(e). Depending on the context, the perpetual storing of data might be justifiable under the GDPR.

Accordingly, it is not necessary for the provider to exclude natural persons merely on grounds of the GDPR.

Comment: OK.So does that mean a term stating "GDPR does not apply" will make the whole terms of service void?

Comment: @compenthusiast No. A contract does not invalidate or suppress the GDPR. That clause would be null and void. Instead, the provider needs to be able to prove [to the authorities or tribunal] that *retaining the data forever* is crucial for the performance contract and not just a matter of arbitrariness or bargaining power. Hence the notion of *[true] necessity* as contemplated in the GDPR.

Comment: So can please clarify that only that clause or the whole agreement will be invalid?

Comment: Only the clauses that contravene the GDPR or other legislation would be invalid, meaning that they will be null and void (see the first sentence in the answer). If there is no *true necessity* for the performance of contract, a user protected by the GDPR is entitled to exercise his right to deletion of his personal data regardless of what the clause says.

Comment: I think that this sort of disclaimer would be valuable as a contrast to the more typical "only any portions of this contract that contravene local law are void, and the the entirety of the rest of the contract is to be held as binding" types of wording that you typically see in EULAs.

Comment: @nick012000 Both alternatives are equally redundant nonetheless. Even if users are unaware of this tenet of contract law (i.e., the principle that only the clauses that contravene statutory law are null and void), a court or tribunal will apply that principle anyway.

Comment: @IñakiViggers I dunno. I think that there's a difference between "clauses that violate statutory law are void and the rest of the contract stands" and "the entire contract is void if any clauses violate statutory law", especially if it's backed up by behavior on the part of the company that makes it clear that they don't intend to offer their software to individuals in areas where that isn't true. You know, something like "We knowingly violate the GDPR, so we deliberately refuse to sell our software services to European customers, so that it doesn't apply to us."

Comment: This is an example of such Terms of Service: https://policy.medium.com/medium-terms-of-service-9db0094a1e0f the servablity clause.

Comment: @compenthusiast I gather you refer to item (h)(1)-(2), which is redundant because it merely restates an elementary principle of contract law (see my comment to nick012000). Courts will apply that principle even if the party was unaware thereof.

Comment: Yeah just gave a refference

Comment: @nick012000 "*there's a difference between  "clauses that [...]*". Your remark is accurate in general. But here it is not that the OP *intends to knowingly violate the GDPR*. The OP's premise only suggests that he was unaware of the criterion of *true necessity* and other exceptions provided in the GDPR. He might want to assess first whether any of these are applicable based on details only he knows. Also it seems untenable for a user to knowingly & willfully consent to *permanent* retention of data and subsequently disrupt functionality merely because later on the user changed his mind.

Answer (score 15):

### Yes, but ...

It doesn’t protect you. Let’s imagine you put such a clause in and a person in Europe used your service notwithstanding: they’ve broken the contract but you’ve broken the law. You get the fine and they get ... nothing. Because you can’t contract outside the law you never had a valid contract with them so you have no basis to sue.

Further, because you are purporting to something you can’t legally do, you are probably on the wrong side of misleading and deceptive consumer protection law: which is another fine.

If you can **ensure** that you don’t breach local law - like by not operating over the internet - then you can choose not to deal with e.g. Europeans. If you can’t guarantee that, then you’re stuffed.

Comment: But can you not ask them to tell you the country they are from, and not provide the service if it's Europe? If they lie, you could not possibly have known it so you should not be responsible?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh If they lie, that gives you a reason to void the contract. It does not give you permission to break the law.

Comment: @DaleM: Nevertheless, it might give rise to a "You (the ECJ) don't have jurisdiction over me because I'm neither in the EU nor intentionally doing business with its citizens" argument. Whether that argument actually *works* is a different matter.

Comment: "you’re stuffed" is probably a bit of exaggeration. If another country wants to hold you accountable for breaking one of their laws, assuming you have no legal presence there (like a subsidiary), that's a rather complex story and it seems unlikely that you'd face many, if any, consequences unless it's a particularly egregious crime. Even aside from that, I'd still be surprised if they're try to hold you accountable for GDPR despite you taking reasonable steps to ensure no-one in those countries uses the service (mentioning it in the contract may not be sufficient for this through).

Comment: [GDPR.EU](https://gdpr.eu/companies-outside-of-europe) does give some guidelines and hints as to what would and wouldn't be allowed: "regulators look for other clues to determine whether the organization set out to offer goods and services to people in the EU" and "Suppose you run a golf course in Manitoba focused exclusively on your local area, but sometimes people in France stumble across your site. Would you find yourself in the crosshairs of European regulators? It’s not likely."

Comment: "If they lie, that gives you a reason to void the contract." - I feel this is missing the point. Which is, that you do not know that they lied, and hence cannot possibly act on it.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh You can't know they lied, so that is exactly why just asking the user 'Are you currently in the EU?' isn't enough. Most 'ethical' services I have seen just applied the GDPR consequences for all countries, other services that do not want to extend the same courtesy to all their customers tend to combine self reported regions with the origin of the connection (if either comes from the EU, assume the user is in the EU).

Comment: @Kevin Unless you have a financial relationship with someone in the EU in general you are practically perfectly safe. Still, offering services in the EU typically comes with a financial relationship with EU subjects (whether it is through ads, through shipping goods to EU customers or through direct subscriptions).

Comment: This answer looks wrong. The GDPR applies to companies doing business in or with the EU. Whether a non-EU business is included will be judged on the whole evidence, including the contract terms. Contract terms that explicitly state the offer is not valid in the EU will weigh towards the conclusion. Other factors (such as a price in euro's) can contradict it, but then those actions would be the basis for the GDPR violation, not the contract.

Comment: The primary question is whether or not a US court would enforce a judgement from an EU court, as EU authorities have zero power over US territory on their own. They might refuse to do so on the basis of US contract law, thus turning the EU judgement into an empty piece of paper. Are there any examples of US courts agreeing to enforce GDPR-related judgement on US territory?

Comment: @JonathanReez I believe there are no GDPR-related fines yet to USA entities without EU representation - there are cases like Mariott International and Google, both of which have clear EU subsidiaries on which fines can be enforced; and of course the vast majority of GDPR enforcement is about local companies and non-Internet uses of data.

Comment: Okay, what about a two-step process? First have the user agree to a contract representing that they are not subject to the GDPR (or more generally, that the intended terms of use -- referenced but *not* incorporated -- are legal in their jurisdiction); *then* offer them the chance to use the service under the terms that violate the GDPR. The first contract is valid even if the user lies, so you could sue the user for consequential damages for breaching it, if you are fined as a result of going through with the second (invalid) contract.

Comment: @nanoman Do you *really* want to be known as "that one service that sues their users"?

Comment: This is an example of such Terms of Service: https://policy.medium.com/medium-terms-of-service-9db0094a1e0f the servablity clause.